# Django uploading multiple media and saving

Tags: python, django

I've tried to research and understand on the documentation, but unable to solve my problem.

I've a ModelForm which allows me to select and upload multiple files.
However, upon saving, only 1 file is saved to my media root folder despite multiple selection.

My guess is that the filename for all files in getlist are same (since they're uploaded at the same time), it overwrites each other in a way and end up only saving 1 media. Appreciate the assistance from the community, thank you !

```
forms.py
class FileFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
stuff_image = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
class Meta:
    model = Thing
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'quantity','stuff_image')
```

--

```
model.py
def generate_filename(instance, filename):
ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
return '' + str(int(time())) + '.' + ext

class Thing(models.Model):  
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
description = models.TextField(blank = True)
quantity = models.IntegerField(blank =True) 
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
stuff_image = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    ordering = ['title']

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Thing)
def stuff_post_delete_handler(sender, **kwargs):
Thing = kwargs['instance']
storage, path = Thing.stuff_image.storage, Thing.stuff_image.path
storage.delete(path)
```

--

```
view.py

def create_stuff(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FileFieldForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    files = request.FILES.getlist('stuff_image')
    if form.is_valid():
        for f in files:
            form.save()
        return redirect('list-stuff')
else:
    form = FileFieldForm()
return render(request, 'stuffapp/create_stuff.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple images linked to `Thing` model, you need to create an `Image` model with ForeignKey of `Thing` model. The FileField can only relate to one file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To upload multiple images/files in django, preferabble use the package django-multiupload, see the (documentation)[https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiupload] or (GitHub Page)[https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload]. Just follow the instructions and the examples. Works flawlessly.